# How to flip a date in PHP

Tags: php

My form inputs a date as dd/mm/yyyy, however my database uses a yyyy-mm-dd format. 
How do I flip the dates into the database format along with the difference of '/' and '-'?

```
$first_date = $_REQUEST["date_1"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($first_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's datetime class:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($first_date);
$dateTime = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```